# How to query third table with hasOne relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs, laravel

I have a **tickets** table. The main tickets table **hasOne** customer. The customer table belongs to the user table.

**Ticket.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
}

/**
 * Get the TicketStatus record associated with the Ticket.
 * One ticket has only one status
 */
public function ticket_status(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\TicketStatus','id','ticket_status_id');
}

/**
 * Get the Customer record associated with the Ticket.
 * One ticket has only one customer
 */
public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer', 'id', 'customer_id');
}
```

**Customer.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * Get the Ticket that owns the Customer.
 */
public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ticket');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer');
}
/**
 * Get the Ticket record associated with the user.
 * 
 */
public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ticket');
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($tickets as $item)
<tr>
     <td>{{ $item->customer->first_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The main table is tickets. It has a **foreign_key to users and customers**. Customers table has a foreign key to user which contains first_name and last_name.

**Problem**: I want to access **$item->customer->first_name**.

> **Error**: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.ticket_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where
>   `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`ticket_id` = 1 and
>   `users`.`ticket_id` is not null limit 1)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your schema and relationship are defined properly then you can write your code as:

```
@foreach($tickets as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->customer->user->first_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

OR

```
@foreach($tickets as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->user->first_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The error you shown is suggesting that the `users` table dosn't contains `ticket_id`. Have you checked it (maybe you forgot about run some migration)?
2. Your main probkem should be solved by changing the relation method in `Ticket` class for that:

---

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer', 'customer_id');
}
```

The second argument should be foreign key from related table (same as with `hasMany` relation).

Comment: Thanks for helping me.